# Failed to access Latitude and Longitude using address.getLatitude() in second setOnClickListener code

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

May I ask, how can I get the ***latitude and longitude*** from the first `setOnClickListener` below and pass it to second `setOnClickListener`? I want to store the latitude and longitude in Firestore by using code in the second `setOnClickListener`. My idea is when I click on the ***Search Icon***, the app will get the latitude and longitude of the location.[image: Location Search]

**First `setOnClickListener` code**

```
searchLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Geocoder geoceoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try{
                    List<Address> addressList = geoceoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 3);

                    if(addressList.size() > 0){
                        //The address variable is declared in the first setOnClickListener.
                        Address address = addressList.get(0);
                        goToLocation(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
.
.
.
```

**Second `setOnClickListener` code**

I failed to access the Latitude and Longitude via `address.getLatitude()` in second `setOnClickListener` block code. I get error:
`Cannot resolve symbol 'address'`

```
create_eventBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Map<String,Object> event = new HashMap<>();
                //Couldn't access the "address" in first setOnClickListener using address.getLatitude
                event.put("eventLocationLat", address.getLatitude);
                event.put("eventLocationLong", address.getLongitude);
                fStore.collection("event").add(event)...;
});
```

So, when the user press the "**Create Event**" button at the bottom, the second `setOnClickListener` will be executed and store the **latitude and longitude** inside the **Firestore**.

[image: Add Event]
[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want to get the latitude and longitude of certain location, stored it in ```double``` variable, but I couldn't find a way to do it...

Comment: ```event.put("eventLocationLat", address.getLatitude);
    event.put("eventLocationLong", address.getLongitude);```
I try to access using ```address.getLatitude```, it appear error:
```Cannot resolve symbol 'address'```

Comment: So, I want to know is there another way that allow me to access the Lat and Long from the second setOnClickListener?

Comment: I apologize if I didn't state clearly regarding the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Cannot resolve symbol 'address'"? Show us the entire error. Maybe a screenshot of it.

Comment: Screenshot of the error added.

Comment: Ok, but please provide a more detailed one, to see how is exactly the address variable defined.

Comment: The ```address``` variable is defined in the if statement in the first ```setOnClickListener()``` block code. I try to access it in the second ```setOnClickListener()``` block code. Then, it appear error. Can you please refer to the first code block and second code block that I have provided?

Comment: Instead of describing how is the variable defined, show us the relevant code. So please edit your question and add the code to see it clearly.

Comment: I already edited the question based on your request. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'address'

Because you have declared the `address` object inside the scope of the first listener. This means that the object is **not** visible inside the second listener, hence the error.

To solve this, declare the variable as a member of the class:

```
private Address address;
```

Initilize it inside the first listener:

```
 address = addressList.get(0);
```

And then simply use it inside your second listener. The error will be gone.

Comment: This is what I need, thank you so much, Alex.